# When you exclude a field from a Django admin class, does that also prevent the field being set in a POST?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Say I have a model admin:

```
class Customer(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=255)
    secret = CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)


@register(Customer)
class CustomerAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name']
    exclude = ['secret']
```

The `secret` field is not going to appear in the admin. But if I programmatically create a `POST` with the `secret` field in, will Django prevent it from being set on the model? So is there any security risk in having an admin class for a model which has excluded fields that should not be written to from a web client?

Comment: If you exclude it, then normally the field is not editable (and thus POST data is ignored). Of course under the assumption that there are no bugs in Django.

Comment: As an aside, it's safer to do `fields = ['name']`. If you use `exclude`, there's a chance that you forget to update `exclude` when you add another field `secret2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is that this should be fine and using `exclude` should be enough to prevent the field being set by a malicious POST.

The reason lies in [`construct_instance()` (django 3.2)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ff514309e178e3955012050ead9b8fc66dc21a5b/django/forms/models.py#L30), which is used to populate a new or existing instance (the `instance` argument) with data from the POST (in the `fields` argument):

```py
def construct_instance(form, instance, fields=None, exclude=None):
    ...
    for f in opts.fields:
        ...
        if exclude and f.name in exclude:
            continue
        ...
        else:
            f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name])
```

Which gets called as:

```py
class BaseModelForm(BaseForm):
    ...
    def _post_clean(self):
        opts = self._meta
        ...
        try:
            self.instance = construct_instance(self, self.instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
        except ValidationError as e:
            ...
```

And the `exclude` is populated by the `django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin`:

```py
class ModelAdmin(BaseModelAdmin):
    ...
    def get_exclude(self, request, obj=None):
        return self.exclude

    ...

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
        ...
        excluded = self.get_exclude(request, obj)
        exclude = [] if excluded is None else list(excluded)
        ...
        defaults = {
            ...
            'exclude': exclude,
            ...
        }
        ...
        try:
            return modelform_factory(self.model, **defaults)
        except FieldError as e:
            ...
```

And `modelform_factory` just passes that through to the form's options.